# Pour preuve et Comme preuve

Tags: sens, usage

Quelle est la différence entre "Pour preuve" et "Comme preuve" ? Laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte ? Si les deux sont correctes, ont-elles le même sens ?

> - J'ai participé à la seconde guerre. Pour preuve, j'ai des cicatrices.
> - J'ai participé à la seconde guerre. Comme preuve, j'ai des cicatrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux sont correctes et ont le même sens.

Le langage est plus soutenu dans la première forme et fait plus littéraire et plus crédible pour quelqu'un ayant fait la seconde guerre mondiale.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication :)

Comment: *Pour preuve* est à nouveau le plus utilisé : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pour+preuve%2C+comme+preuve&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpour%20preuve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomme%20preuve%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @cl-r Merci pour m'avoir fait découvrir cet outil :)